# Using z-index to make one nested element in front of other element?

Tags: html, css

My code looks like this:

```
css:

.top {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height: 1600px;
width: 100%;
z-index: -100;

}

.bar {
position: relative;
z-index: -200;
width: 100%
height: 100px;

}

.inner-bar {
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%
height: 50px;

}



html:

<body>
<div class="top">some content</div>

<div class="bar"> 
  <div class="inner-bar">some content</div>
<div>

</body>
```

As you can see I am trying to make inner-bar appear in front but this does not work. Once I set bar to be behind of everything ( which works) this also sets inner-bar to be behind of everything no mater what styling I do for inner-bar. My layout requires that inner-bar must be a child of bar. So is there a solution and what it is?

To make it clear my objective is to make bar behind top (content in top appears on bar) and to make top behind inner-bar ( content in top is hidden if it overlaps inner-bar so that the links in inner-bar are active).

Comment: from the moment you have `z-index:-200` for `.bar` how will be in front of the `.top` which has `z-index:-100`? If understand correct, you have to remove the `z-index` for `.bar` and use the `z-index` of `.inner-bar` only.

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361359/how-can-i-get-desired-z-index-behavior-from-ie-when-using-nested-divs

Comment: Use of negative `z-index` often ends up with *something* being unselectable or unclickable. Because of this highly annoying tendency, it's best used with caution.

Comment: Soltris I want bar to be behind top but inner-bar to be in front of top as stated in the question. Tried your suggestion but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off there is an error in the html you posted:

```
<body>
    <div class="top">some content</div>
    <div class="bar"> 
      <div class="inner-bar">some content</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

you didn't close the last div :)

as for the rest:

here you go good sir! http://jsfiddle.net/8AJnD/31/

```
.top {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 1600px;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;left:0;z-index:0;
}

.bar {
    position: absolute;z-index:-1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;top:0;left:0
}

.inner-bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-2;
    width: 100%
    height: 50px;top:0;left:0
}
```

Use absolute instead of relative and make the parent relative to be able to position the elements however you want them to be positioned

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all ```.top``` is over ```.inner-bar```.

Comment: @Korri, not in my jsfiddle :s

Comment: yes in your jsfiddle, tryed it under Chrome and Firefox and both show the red/yellow text (```.top```) on top.

Comment: Nope, quote the question: "As you can see I am trying to make inner-bar appear in front but this does not work."

Comment: If you replace the text with images instead of identical text, the top "some content" stays on top.

Answer (score 0):

Negative z-index values have strange behavior. I don't believe that they work in "layers" like you would expect, rather they all wind up on the same "layer". Try using positive z-index values instead:

```
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 1600px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;    
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but unfortunately this does not work and makes it even worse because (I think) default z-index is zero for other elements. In this case all the links in all other elements including those that are statically positioned becomes unclickable as the top layer now is on top of it.